# QGIS - Attempting to Locate a Single Line Layer within Thousands of Point Layers

Tags: search, geometry, line, point, qgis

I am trying to merge approximately 2000 Point layers into a single layer, but I keep getting the error upon merge that there is one or possibly two line layers in the selection preventing the merge.

Its unfortunate that there is not an option to select which geometry types you want to merge so it just ignores the others.

Also i am finding the Point and Line symbol much too similar to be able to identify the single line layer in 2000+ point layers.

Is there a way to search the layer panel for specific geometry types, organize it by type, or conditional format the layers by type to highlight a line layer if needed?

I have searched for over an hour now and i cannot locate this layer that's preventing me from merging the point layers.

Visually searching the layer panel as i cannot think of any other way to find a specific geometry type in the list of layers.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by going to a browser in qgis and search the GPKG that contains all of those layers. Then right click the gpkg and "execute SQL".

Write this command into the query space:

```sql
SELECT * FROM gpkg_contents WHERE table_name IN (SELECT table_name FROM gpkg_geometry_columns WHERE geometry_type_name = 'POINT');
```

This will select you only the layer inside the geopackage, that have geometry type as POINTS. Then tap open the lowest option menu "load as new layer". Copy the code to that first row, and give that layer a name. Then "load layer".